# How to use progress bar and swipe refresh at the same fragment?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `ProgressBar` (with counting) to load a web site.
I'm using `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` to connect to internet when internet disconnected.
and
I'm using **Custom error.html** page to instead of default No internet connection page.

Before I added swipe refresh layout, progressbar was fine. After adding swipe refresh layout, progressbar doesn't work. 
I want connect above 3 items.(progress bar,swipe refresh and custom error page)
So I connected all codes.but not working properly.Please can you help me ?
thank to you.

**web_view.java**

```
public class web_view extends AppCompatActivity {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url="http://blog.google.com";
    TextView textView;
    //to hide progressbar after loading part 1
    LinearLayout liProgressContainer;
    private String currentUrl;
    private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_train);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoadingPercentage);
        //to hide progressbar after loading part 2
        liProgressContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liProgressContainer);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });
        LoadWeb();
   }

    public void LoadWeb()
    {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()
        {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view,int errorCode,String description ,String failingUrl )
            {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String url)
            {
                swipe.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + " %");
            }
        });
    }


   //back button function
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //hide header part
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_webview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".web_view">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liProgressContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoadingPercentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/liProgressContainer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/liProgressContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:indeterminate="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLoadingPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/liProgressContainer">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your web_view activity code with this code

```
public class web_view extends AppCompatActivity {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url = "http://blog.google.com";
    TextView textView;
    //to hide progressbar after loading part 1
    LinearLayout liProgressContainer;
    private String currentUrl;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tvLoadingPercentage);
        //to hide progressbar after loading part 2
        liProgressContainer = findViewById(R.id.liProgressContainer);
        swipe = findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + " %");
            }
        });

        WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });

        LoadWeb();
    }

    public void LoadWeb() {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    }


    //back button function
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: X-Byte ..Thank you.It's working for xml code.Do u hve any idea for webview.java code.because swipe not working and progress bar not hiding after loading 100%.

Comment: for that you have to show hide views programmatically  based on requirement

Comment: X-Byte.It's not working.
hope my web_view.java contains errors....can you correct it....I  have no idea about it...
*After loading web site,progress bar should hide.
*swipe should work
*when load custom error.html page back button not working..why is that?

Comment: all **MyUtils** getting with Red Color..why is that?

Comment: @Mr.Soft yes remove MyUtils.Log(... that all lines, actually this is my  constant log file reference

Comment: Code working,but I can't see webviewChromeClient.because I want to see **progress bar percentage** marks...
/////////////////////////////////////////code/////////////////////////////////////

 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + " %");
            }
        });.

Comment: then add that simple

Comment: @X-Byte..I have a small question...Let's say after loading a website,we are scrolling down.After that If we want to going up we are scrolling up..
In my case scrolling up not working then swipe works.I want to swipe start top of the web site only.How to resolve it...Thank you..

Comment: @Mr.Soft check my answer xml file

Comment: You are life saver..Thank you once again..Thank you

Comment: @X-Byte..I have 2 small questions...If you can please help me.... **1)** back button is not working properly in custom_error.html page(when internet disconnected).Why is that? 
**2)** when we swipe refresh down a inner page of web site,it will go to home page.I want to refresh the page we are looking at.

can you edit the code please.I appreciate your help.Thank you –

Comment: above web_view activity(your answer) is my sourcecode.Can't you edit it.

Comment: how can I send it again,to where ?

Comment: and the second option is you can do it your self just find how to detect currently loaded URL in Webview and load that URL while Pull to refresh call.

Comment: Here is my sourcecode zip version. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tCEv5KOKrgGHh7LcvhHXLuKb11vxKA38/view

Hope you will help me to resolve 2nd question also...I searched in google .but I didn't found any answers...Thank you

Comment: I found this code ,and I dont know how to implement it....
**function reloadWebview(page: Page, webview: WebView): void {
    if (isString(webview.url) && webview.url.length > 0) {
        webview.reload();
    } else {
        // webview.reload() wouldn't do the trick because the url is lost
        // due to an error that occurred on the initial load
        webview.stopLoading();
        webview.url = page.navigationContext.url;
    }
}**

Comment: Dude Did you check my sourcecode..Thank you..I will appreciate your help...

Comment: I'm waiting for you.Please can you give me an answer..?

Comment: X-Byte  Are you there?

Comment: X-Byte please can you do me that flavor...Thank you

Comment: @Mr.Soft please add new question for your new issue